# receiving HTTP requests in c++ using libcurl

Tags: c++, http, server, libcurl

I have python client that sends HTTP requests using `requests.post`
and a c++ server that should receive it. I used

```
    char* data = new char[len + 1];
    int res = recv(client, data, len, 0);

    if (res == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::string s = "Error while recieving from socket: ";
        s += std::to_string(client);
        throw std::exception(s.c_str());
    }
    data[len] = '\0';
    std::cout << "MSG FROM USER: " << data << std::endl;
    std::string temp = data;
    delete[] data;
```

as receiving the request from the user, is there a way to handle it with libcurl?

I used general request handler, and I couldn't find a way to handle it as HTTP with libcurl

Comment: libcurl implements an HTTP client, not a server, which instead is what you want here.

Comment: The name cURL is "client URL". I think the name answers your question negatively.

Answer (score 0):

you shuold be using tcp sockets for connection (4), libcurl is for higher level (7) of connection ,  [this should help](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) , and also see [this](https://www.imperva.com/learn/application-security/osi-model/)